# Module pattern & "private attributes"

Tags: javascript, private-members, module-pattern

Ok, so a couple of weeks ago, I learned about the "module pattern" in javascript. All the examples that I found went basically like that :

```
var module = (function () {
    // private variables and functions
    var foo = 'bar';

    // constructor
      var module = function () {
    };

    // public methods
    module.prototype = {
        something: function () {
        }
    };

    // return module
    return module;
})();

var my_module = new module();
```

I was very excited, so I immediately started my own test :

```
var myModule = myModule || {};

myModule.User = (function(){
    "use strict";

    // "private" attribut
    var id

    //constructor
    var User = function(l_id){
        id = l_id;
    };

    //"public" method
    User.prototype.getId = function(){ return id };


    return User;
})();

var u2 = new myModule.User(2);
var u1 = new myModule.User(1);
console.log(u2.getId()); // print 2
console.log(u1.getId()); //print 2 oO
```

However, I didn't expect that the so called "private" attribut "id", was not an instance variable. And if I had paid attention, I would have noticed the scope of such a variable... I terribly misunderstood the "private variables and functions" comment...

Nevertheless, I was determined to found a way to used private instance variable within a module.

For the moment the only solution I found is this good old way :

```
myModule.User = (function(){
    "use strict";

    //constructor
    var User = function(id){        
        this.getId = function(){ return id; };
    };   

    return User;
})();
```

But there is no prototype avantages anymore...

Do you have a better way to mixe the "module pattern" and the use of private instance variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Well frankly speaking I've never used the Module pattern with a constructor, I feel there are better ways, however to achieve what you're looking for (that is if I understood you correct) you can do something like this:

```
var PrefixModule = (function () {
    // this is going to be static ... also that's a real title !
    var staticTitle = "Intergalactic Federation King Almighty and Commander of the Universe";

    var PrefixModule = function () {
        // this is an instance variable
        this.secretPrefix = staticTitle + " ::";
    };

    // hidden from the world
    var generateRandomNumber = function() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    };

    PrefixModule.prototype.PrefixName = function (name) {
        var randomNumber = generateRandomNumber();
        return this.secretPrefix + " " + name + " | " + randomNumber;
    };

    return PrefixModule;
})();

var m1 = new PrefixModule();
var m2 = new PrefixModule();
var m3 = new PrefixModule();

console.log(m1.PrefixName("Jon Skeet"));
console.log(m2.PrefixName("Chuck Norris"));
console.log(m3.PrefixName("vbarthel-fr"));
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LdTQL/).

Also, I should clarify that in your case the `id` is set as a static variable and it's shared between modules.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me to better understand the "module" thing: the module scope is for static shared variables!

Comment: Feel free to accept it as an answer if it's what you're looking for :)